# How to list field annotations in Kotlin?

Tags: annotations, kotlin

I have an annotation

```
public @interface Field {
    String value();
}
```

and java class, annotated by it:

```
public class Animal {
    @Field("name")
    private String name;
}
```

I try to list all field' annotations by the next code:

```
for(field in clazz.declaredFields){
            for(annotation in field.annotations){
                when(annotation){
                     is Field -> {
                         //do something
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

where clazz is `Class<T>`

but `field.annotations` is empty.

How to list annotations correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue isn't Kotlin specific, you just haven't configured `Field` annotation properly. By default, each annotation is retained with [`RetentionPolicy.CLASS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#CLASS), meaning it won't be accessible via reflection. You have to use [`RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html#RUNTIME) if you want to access the annotation in the runtime.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Field {
  String value();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get @Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS) annotation's value in Kotlin?

I need to get entities from Room's Database annotation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Database

Answer (score 7):

Java annotations, by default, are not retained at runtime so you'll need to specify such:

```java
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Field {
    String value();
}
```

[Kotlin annotations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html) are retained by default:

```kotlin
annotation class Field(val value: String)
```